# Java Application send mail from laptop but not from windows Server

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a simple servletapp  which sends mail using the Googles smtp server i.e smtp.gmail.com.

I used the servlet code from from below link , as i am note a java devloper b have some knowledge of java:

http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/Sending-email-using-servlet.php

I have 2 tomcats , one is installed on my laptop and one is installed on a windows server on same network(both tomcat same version and using jdk and jre installed is of same version)

The issue is when I run the application from my local laptop, I get the mails in my inbox , but when run the application from the Winndows server , i do not get email in my inbox.

Ports are not blocked as I able to telnet on both port 587 and 465.
Also , I can send mail via command line using openssl from my laptop and the windows server.

IpV6 is disabled on both laptop and  windows server as I read some where that is causes issue with javamail.

Regards, 
R

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?